# How to Update Value Based on the Displayed row in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to update my data in MySQL database using the displayed data from it. But I haven't much luck in figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I don't know how can I pass my data from my $rows in order for me to use it in my UPDATE SQL statement.

I just want to complete all the data before I clicked the save button.

Please see attached image for the output..
 [image]
And also, I got a warning message like this.

WHenever I Clicked the Save Data button..

**Notice: Undefined variable: reason in C:\xampp\htdocs\BTR\get_forms.php on line 109**

**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\BTR\get_forms.php on line 109**

Can someone enlighten me.. How to do this.? Thank you..

```
 <?php

    require 'config.php';


    $form_type = $_POST['form_type'];

    if ($form_type == 'MCCV-F2'){

        $region = $_POST['region'];
        $province = $_POST['province'];
        $municipality = $_POST['municipality'];
        $barangay = $_POST['barangay'];
        $period = $_POST['period'];
        $form_type = $_POST['form_type'];

            echo "NON COMPLIANT IN EDUCATION<br>";
            echo "<br><br>MUNICIPALITY: ".$municipality;
            echo "<br><br>BARANGAY: ".$barangay;
            echo "<br><br>PERIOD: ".$period;
?>

        <form name="get_forms_f2" action="" method="post">
            <br><br>
            <center><table border = 1 style =2 width=1800>
            <tr>
                <td><center><b>Household ID </center></td>
                <td><center><b>Member ID </center></td>
                <td><center><b>Name</center></td>
                <td><center><b>Sex</center></td>
                <td><center><b>HH Status</center></td>
                <td><center><b>Grade Level </center></td>
                <td><center><b>School ID</center></td>
                <td><center><b>Name Of Dominant School</center></td>
                <td><center><b>CV Remarks</center></td>
                <td><center><b>Reason</center></td>
                <td><center><b>Other Reason</center></td>
                <td><center><b>Intervention</center></td>
            </tr>

            <?php   

                $sql = "SELECT A.family_id, A.barangay, A.person_id, A.gender, A.family_status, A.current_grade_level,
                A.school_facility_id, A.school_facility_name, A.municipality, CONCAT(B.last_name, ', ',B.first_name) as 'name',
                B.person_id,B.cv_remarks, B.reason, B.other_reason, B.intervention, B.status FROM roster AS A RIGHT JOIN compliance AS B ON A.person_id = B.person_id 
                WHERE B.period='$period' AND B.form_type='$form_type' AND A.municipality='$municipality' AND A.barangay='$barangay'";
                $query=$conn->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute();
                $result= $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $count=(int)$query->rowCount();

                    foreach ($result as $row){

                        $person_id[] = $row['person_id'];

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['family_id']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['person_id']."</td>"; 
                        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['gender']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['family_status']."</td>";  
                        echo "<td>".$row['current_grade_level']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['school_facility_id']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['school_facility_name']."</td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='text' name='cv_remarks[]' value='".$row['cv_remarks']."'></td>";

                        echo "<td><select name='reason[]'>";

                                if (is_null($row['reason'])){

                                    $sql2= "SELECT reason_code, reason_desc FROM reasons WHERE form_type ='2' ORDER BY reason_code ASC";
                                    echo "<option value=''>SELECT REASON FOR Non-Compliance</option>";
                                    foreach($conn->query($sql2) as $row2){
                                        echo "<option value='".$row2['reason_desc']."'>".$row2['reason_code']." - ".$row2['reason_desc']."</option>";
                                        }
                                }

                                if (!is_null($row['reason'])){


                                    $sql2= "SELECT reason_code, reason_desc FROM reasons WHERE form_type ='2' ORDER BY reason_code ASC";
                                    echo "<option value='".$row['reason']."'>".$row['reason']." (SELECTED)"."</option>";
                                        foreach($conn->query($sql2) as $row2){
                                        echo "<option value='".$row2['reason_desc']."'>".$row2['reason_code']." - ".$row2['reason_desc']."</option>";
                                        }
                                }

                        echo "</select></td>";

                        echo "<td><input type='text' name='other_reason[]' value='".$row['other_reason']."'></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='text' name='intervention[]' value='".$row['intervention']."'></td>"; 
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }

        }
            ?>
            </table></center><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">

        <?php

        $sql3 = "UPDATE compliance SET reason='{$reason}' WHERE person_id='{$person_id}' AND form_type='$form_type' AND period='$period'";
                $query = $conn->prepare($sql3);
                $query->execute();
        ?>
        </form>
```

Comment: While using array in update you have yo use json_encode to save the datas to database `json_encode($_POST['reason']);` like this you have to do for all array varialble..

Comment: Sir thank you for your reply.. But I don't know where will I put that pieces of code.. Can you give me an example.. 

Sorry but I'm just new to the language and I'm just starting to learn it..

Comment: bro you are using array for single select option and it looks meaningless since if it is a multiple select you can use array.

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste the Insert and Edit form that you have  coded.

Comment: Sir I already Edited my question.. Thank you..

Comment: Will post you the answer. You check it asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted with the answer of how to update form with an array variable as a whole.

I have kept person,reason as array since you have added that alone as array().

```
    <?php
require 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['person_id']); $i++)
{
$sql3 = "UPDATE compliance SET reason='".$_POST['reason'][$i]."' WHERE person_id='".$_POST['person_id'][$i]."' AND form_type='".$_POST['form_type']."' AND period='".$_POST['period']."'";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql3);
$query->execute();
}// end of For
}// end of IF
$form_type = $_POST['form_type'];
if ($form_type == 'MCCV-F2'){
$region = $_POST['region'];
$province = $_POST['province'];
$municipality = $_POST['municipality'];
$barangay = $_POST['barangay'];
$period = $_POST['period'];

echo "NON COMPLIANT IN EDUCATION<br>";
echo "<br><br>MUNICIPALITY: ".$municipality;
echo "<br><br>BARANGAY: ".$barangay;
echo "<br><br>PERIOD: ".$period;
?>

<form name="get_forms_f2" action="" method="post">
<br><br>
<center><table border = 1 style =2 width=1800>
<tr>
<td><center><b>Household ID </center></td>
<td><center><b>Member ID </center></td>
<td><center><b>Name</center></td>
<td><center><b>Sex</center></td>
<td><center><b>HH Status</center></td>
<td><center><b>Grade Level </center></td>
<td><center><b>School ID</center></td>
<td><center><b>Name Of Dominant School</center></td>
<td><center><b>CV Remarks</center></td>
<td><center><b>Reason</center></td>
<td><center><b>Other Reason</center></td>
<td><center><b>Intervention</center></td>
</tr>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT A.family_id, A.barangay, A.person_id, A.gender, A.family_status, A.current_grade_level,
A.school_facility_id, A.school_facility_name, A.municipality, CONCAT(B.last_name, ', ',B.first_name) as 'name',
B.person_id,B.cv_remarks, B.reason, B.other_reason, B.intervention, B.status FROM roster AS A RIGHT JOIN compliance AS B ON A.person_id = B.person_id
WHERE B.period='$period' AND B.form_type='$form_type' AND A.municipality='$municipality' AND A.barangay='$barangay'";
$query=$conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result= $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count=(int)$query->rowCount();

foreach ($result as $row){
?>
<input type="hidden" name="person_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['person_id'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="<?php echo $form_type; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="period" value="<?php echo $period; ?>">
<?php
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['family_id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['person_id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['gender']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['family_status']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['current_grade_level']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['school_facility_id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['school_facility_name']."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='cv_remarks[]' value='".$row['cv_remarks']."'></td>";

echo "<td><select name='reason[]'>";

if (is_null($row['reason'])){

$sql2= "SELECT reason_code, reason_desc FROM reasons WHERE form_type ='2' ORDER BY reason_code ASC";
echo "<option value=''>SELECT REASON FOR Non-Compliance</option>";
foreach($conn->query($sql2) as $row2){
echo "<option value='".$row2['reason_desc']."'>".$row2['reason_code']." - ".$row2['reason_desc']."</option>";
}
}

if (!is_null($row['reason'])){


$sql2= "SELECT reason_code, reason_desc FROM reasons WHERE form_type ='2' ORDER BY reason_code ASC";
echo "<option value='".$row['reason']."'>".$row['reason']." (SELECTED)"."</option>";
foreach($conn->query($sql2) as $row2){
echo "<option value='".$row2['reason_desc']."'>".$row2['reason_code']." - ".$row2['reason_desc']."</option>";
}
}

echo "</select></td>";

echo "<td><input type='text' name='other_reason' value='".$row['other_reason']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='intervention' value='".$row['intervention']."'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

}// end of MCCV-F2 form
?>
</table>
</center>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

Hope so this would solve your problem br. have a try and let me know if any hindrance you find.

Comment: Sir I'm receiving an Error.. I applied the code that you have given to me.. Notice: Undefined index: form_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\BTR\get_forms.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: person_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\BTR\get_forms.php on line 14

Comment: use this for person_id `echo "<input type="hidden" name="person_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['person_id']">"` instead of the previous code `$person_id[] = $row['person_id'];`

Comment: Apply the same for **form_type** and **period** also pass these variables in `<input type="hidden">` as you will do for the person_id .

Comment: Now what error are you facing. Sure if you use hidden field the person_id error will not come.

Comment: Can you post how have you added the input hidden fields and where have you placed.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 17 in C:\xampp\htdocs\BTR\get_forms.php on line 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121136/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-blite-exe).